# how to include .hrl files across multiple modules rebar3

Tags: erlang, rebar, rebar3, relx

I have several modules's directories. For each module, I have `include` (containing `*.hrl` files) and `src` (containing `*.erl` files) folder separeated. How can I share `*.hrl` file from a module to another without duplicating them?

With rebar, I added `{erl_opts, [{i, "folderContainsIncludeFile"}]}` and it worked.

But with rebar3, the compilation is failed by saying can't find include file "include/xx.hrl"

Comment: Have you tried using `-include_lib` instead of `-include`?

Comment: yes, I have tried but it is not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it then you don't have an umbrella project, you just have multiple directories at the same level, each one with its own project managed with rebar3.
Something like:

```
root_folder
 |- project1
 |  |- src
 |  |- include
 |  |  `- one.hrl
 |  `- rebar.config
 |- project2
 |  |- src
 |  |  `- two.erl
 |  |- include
 |  `- rebar.config
 …
```

And you want to include `one.hrl` into `two.erl`.

If that's the case, you should consider one of these alternatives:

A. Moving to an umbrella project structure, like…

```
root_folder
 |- rebar.config <<<<<<<< notice this file is here now
 `- apps
    |- project1
    |  |- src
    |  `- include
    |     `- one.hrl
    |- project2
    |  |- src
    |  |  `- two.erl
    |  `- include
    …
```

B. Using individual repos for each project and configuring them as dependencies from each other. The structure is like the one you currently have, but now you have to add `deps` to rebar.config's. For instance, in our example, you should add the following line to project2's rebar.config:

```
{deps, [project1]}.
```

(if you manage to publish project1 in hex.pm)

C. Properly setting `$ERL_LIBS` so that it includes the paths where your apps are built with rebar3. Something like…

```
ERL_LIBS=$ERL_LIBS:/path/to/root_folder/project1/_build/lib:/path/to/root_folder/project2/_build/lib:…
```

Hope this helps :)